# I need to implement a ​SparseArray​ with a ​linked list​ implementation

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, linked-list

sparse
array objects will have a fixed size ​n ​ set when they are created - attempting to set or get elements larger
than the size of the array should raise an ​IndexError

Comment: Have you tried anything? If you post what you have tried and the problems or errors that you have encounter people will more likely help you. No one wants to write code for you!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Scipy sparse Matrics](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) e.g. COO sparse matrix

```
matrix = sparse.coo_matrix((C,(A,B)),shape=(5,5))
```

Or you can use Pandas [sparseArray](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/sparse.html) :

```
arr = np.random.randn(10)
arr[2:5] = np.nan; arr[7:8] = np.nan

sparr = pd.SparseArray(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet these are already implemented in numpy or scipy.